# Отслеживание дополнительных кнопок на мышке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

Здравствуйте. Необходимо отслеживать нажатия на ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ кнопки на мышке (скажем, стрелки на преимущественно игровых мышках). С помощью `pynput` могу отслеживать нажатия на ЛКМ, ПКМ, колёсико, а так же передвижения. Но на доп. кнопки не реагирует. Подскажите, как отслеживать дополнительные клавиши?

```
from pynput import mouse


def on_move(x, y):
    pass


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print(button)


def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scroll')


with mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_move,
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

P.S. отслеживание клавиатуры тоже не работает. Мышь марки Mosunx

Answer (score 2):

Думаю стоит посмотреть доки по самой мышке, вполне может быть (я не утверждаю, не сталкивался), что доп кнопки на мыше работают как кнопки клавиатуры или их сочетание. Попробуйте добавить код прослушивания клавы и понажимать на доп кнопки мыши:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Если не получится, добавьте в Ваш вопрос марку мыши.

Comment: К сожалению, отслеживание клавиатуры тоже не работает. Марку добавил.

Comment: @dtcobra мышей mosunx много, какая серия?